# Ir a otra pagina al pulsar boton dentro de un iframe con Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net

Tengo una pagina llamada pagina1.html y dentro de ella un iframe.En el iframe tengo un formulario con un botón que quiero que cuando se pulse pase de la pagina1.html a otra llamada pagina2.html que contendrá otro iframe con otro formulario.

Para cambiar de pagina le he puesto un evento al botón y dentro el método Response.Redirect pero no me redirige bien a la pagina2.html

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("../pagina2.html");
}
```

Comment: Cuando editas tu pregunta, agrega al cuerpo de la misma lo que modificaste, sino sacas completamente de contexto la respuesta de @Emiliano Montesdeoca

Comment: Ok, ya comente que fuer un error al redactarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actualización 2** con version para Visual Studio 2008 y .NET 3.5, [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager(v=vs.90).aspx) tienes la documentación de esa version, y como puedes ver es la misma forma que en la version actual pero menos refactorizado.

Tienes agregado el namespace **`System.Web.UI`**?

```
  // Esto lo tienes?
  using System.Web.UI;

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // Definir que vas a ejecutar en Javascript y el tipo
   String script = "window.parent.location = '../pagina2.html'";
   Type cstype = this.GetType();

   // ClientScriptManager para la pagina
   ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Ejecutar el scriptblock
   cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, script, script.ToString(), false);
  }
```

*Actualiza ese VS!*

**Actualizo** con una nueva propuesta ya que no era un error de comillas.

Se puede hacer con Javascript con el objecto **`window.parent`** ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent)) y la propiedad **`location`**, para llamarlo desde .NET utiliza el **`ClientScriptManager`** ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
       "RedirectScript", "window.parent.location = '../pagina2.html'", true);
}
```

Comment: No, no era ese el error, me equivoque al redactarlo. Ya esta corregido.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, a ver si te funciona ahora.

Comment: Dentro del método me reconoce el ClientScriptManager pero no el RegisterClientScriptBlock . Estoy usando Visual Studio 2008, FrameWork 3.5.

Comment: Ahora si me funcióna, lo he puesto como Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock() que seria lo mismo que me has indicado . ¿ Si en vez de cambiar a otra pagina cambio solo el interior del iframe con otra  dirección  para que no se me vea tanta recarga de pagina ? ¿ Como lo tendría que implementar?

Comment: Simple, con Javascript tienes que cambiar el `src` del iframe, por ejemplo: `document.getElementById['iframe'].src = '../pagina2.html';`, donde el `'iframe'` es el `id` de tu iframe.

Comment: Me pasa una cosa muy extraña, cuando pulso el botón dentro del iFrame a veces tengo que volver a pulsar en alguna zona dentro del iFrame, o volver a recargar la pagina con CTR+F5 y luego pulsar otra vez al botón iFrame para que me redirija a la otra pagina.

Comment: Puse el botón dentro de un UpdatePanel porque también lo necesitaba y ahora no me funciona la implementación de ir a otra pagina. !!!

Comment: Puede que se comporten de diferente forma, te recomiendo que cierres esta pregunta ya que esta solucionada y hagas una nueva con problema nuevo y el codigo de Update Panel asi podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Ok gracias, así lo haré